# marks with fullline visualization

Tags: highlight, mark

There is any solution to highlight the entire line where a mark has been inserted (e.g. with command `ma`)?

The best could be to have marked each mark with a different color of choice.

Any idea?

Thanks
giorgio

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to do this natively, but it sounds like a fun plugin to write. If there's no answers on this after several hours I'll take a stab at it and update here.

Comment: btw, a gist could be that each time one set a mark ( ma, mb, mc, etc.), a different (transparent) color is take to highlight the marked line, or just use a fixed sequence of colors or just a unique color... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I [created a plugin](https://github.com/Tumbler/highlightMarks) that I think does what you want.

If you want to change the colors that it uses simply define `g:highlightMarks_colors` in your `vimrc` as a list of colors (either names or RGB strings).

I welcome any feedback you have.

Screenshot as example:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic!  
Minor change: I would prefer color on ALL the line (not just covering text), see line 16 of this screenshot:  
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/17814403_10212119124231225_4830943041494897449_o.jpg?oh=c5aa64a3d8a72eb277e927351b617867&oe=598F9A09

BTW,  for cursorline at line 16 I use:
`autocmd InsertLeave,WinEnter * set cursorline
356 autocmd InsertEnter,WinLeave * set nocursorline`

In that way the mark would be more visible. 

Easy to modify? 
Thanks @Tumbler41

Comment: Hmm... I think the only way to do that is with [`signs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/sign.txt.html#%3Asign). Those are line based, so I'd be worried they'd get un-synced with the mark. I'll play around a little and update if I get anything useful.

Comment: Updated with the option to use signs. Put `let g:highlightMarks_useSigns = 1` in your `vimrc`. (Also fixed two small bugs)

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for!  minor side effect: the initial vertical line (on each window), but maybe is because signs enabled...isn'it? 

see: 

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/17834363_10212129674254969_5527169945540607483_o.jpg?oh=eb574d5cad2e2a8d3a0bbfccfa4a2ab1&oe=599862B6 

can I avoid the line? 

Note 1: I'll do some test with `g:highlightMarks_colors` (transparency and I'll try to contribute to your github repo). 

Note 2: `:RemoveMarkHighlights` is perfect for me.

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Yup, it's a side effect of using signs. If you look at the documentation, you'll see I mention that. It's one of the reasons I left signs as an option and not just the new way to do it. Unfortunately, I think that's the only way to get the full line highlighting like you want.

Comment: @GiorgioRobino Thinking about some other features. If you'd like [you could join me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56728/highlight-marks-plugin) for some theory-crafting.

Comment: thx ! counter-propose using e-mail (I got your from https://github.com/Tumbler) and my mail is at  https://github.com/solyaris :). I'll send you soon few thoughts