# Plugin for showing marks by *highlighting entire line*, instead of using signcolumn?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, navigation, mark

I write code mostly on my laptop for portability. It's a small monitor, so plugins that use the "sign column" tend to take up too much space. For example, I have my `Syntastic` plugin configured to **highlight lines with syntax errors in red** and show a message at the bottom, rather than indicating errors in the signcolumn.

Is there a plugin for **navigation between marks**, for which I can do something similar -- just **highlight the entire line** in one or two colors? Generally, I won't be using more than a couple marks in an entire file because I won't remember where they are, and I can navigate lines that fit on the screen with simple `j`/`k` commands.

Maybe I can insert a few lines into my `.vimrc` myself -- for example, trigger a special syntax coloring wherever "mark `A`" is?

Comment: See this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11986/13728.  You might be able to turn off the signcolumn also.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty quick and dirty way using `\%'a`:

```
for c in map(range(char2nr('a'), char2nr('z')), 'nr2char(v:val)')
    call matchadd('Search', '^.*\%'."'".c.'.*$')
endfor
```

Replace `Search` with an appropriate highlighting group.  You can also replace the `map(range(...))` with any set of marks you want, e.g., `['A', 'B']`.

A few caveats:

- Only highlights behind characters, not to the end of the screen.
- Updates only when cursor is moved.